# How do I reuse NonAction methods between controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

Lets say I have a controller class like this.

```
public class InStorePickupController : Controller
{
    private readonly IToppingService _toppingService;
    public InStorePickupController(IToppingService toppingService)
    {
        this._toppingService = toppingService;
    }

    public ActionResult GetPizza()
    {
        var pizzaModel = new PizzaModel();
        pizzaModel = MakePizza(pizzaModel);
        return View(pizzaModel);
    }

    [NonAction]
    public PizzaModel MakePizza(PizzaModel pm)
    {
        var toppings = _toppingService.GetAllToppings();
        //roll out dough
        //put toppings on pizza
        //bake pizza
        return pm;
    }

}
```

But I also have another controller class where I want to use the same 'Make Pizza' non action.

```
public class DeliveryController : Controller
        {
            private readonly IToppingService _toppingService;
            public DeliveryController(IToppingService toppingService)
            {
                this._toppingService = toppingService;
            }

            public ActionResult GetPizza()
            {
                var pizzaModel = new PizzaModel();
                pizzaModel = MakePizza(pizzaModel);
                return View(pizzaModel);
            }
    }
```

This is a simple example but it matches my real situation very closely.  The only difference is that:

1. I have several non action methods and they are fairly involved (lots of calculations).
2. I have quite a few controllers that need access to these non actions.  This isn't controller creep so consolidating them won't work.
3. Each controller has quite a few necessary services in the constructor.

I could have each controller inherit from a base controller class but I keep getting complaints about a parameter-less constructor.

What about static classes?

I just need a little guidance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base class is potentially the way to go, whereby you could do something like:

```
public class PizzaControllerBase : Controller
{
  protected readonly IToppingService ToppingService;

  protected PizzaControllerBase(IToppingService toppingService)
  {
    ToppingService = toppingService;
  }

  public PizzaModel MakePizza(PizzaModel model)
  {
    // Stuff
  }
}

public DeliveryController : PizzaControllerBase
{
  public DeliveryController(IToppingService toppingService)
    : base(toppingService) { }

  public ActionResult GetPizza()
  {
    var pizzaModel = MakePizza(new PizzaModel());
    return View(pizzaModel);
  }
}
```

Or, introduce a new service, the `IPizzaService`:

```
public interface IPizzaService
{
  PizzaModel MakePizza(PizzaModel model);
}

public class PizzaService : IPizzaService
{
  private readonly IToppingService ToppingService;

  public PizzaService(IToppingService toppingService)
  {
    ToppingService = toppingService;
  }

  public PizzaModel CreatePizza(PizzaModel model)
  {
    // Stuff
  }
}
```

Which you can inject into your controller instead.

Comment: In the end I decided to go with a base controller class.  As much as I would have liked to push some of the work into my service layer, many of the "NonActions" take a Pizza and use multiple services to help build it.  This would mean I would have to start mixing my IDoughService in my IToppingService constructor which I don't want to do. If a controller is a traffic cop then I am comfortable with a base controller class handling some of the heavy lifting in getting out my pizza.  Thanks Matthew.

Answer (score 4):

The `[NonAction]` attribute is a code smell for me. It means that you put some code into the controller but for me there shouldn't be any other code in a controller than slim actions. And trying to reuse a `NonAction` between controllers is a confirmation that you are doing something wrong. That's why you have service layers, repositories, models, ... so many places to refactor this code out and [put your controllers on a diet](http://www.viddler.com/explore/mvcconf/videos/1/).

Comment: I agree on using thin controllers. I just want to manipulate everything on the model before saving to my service layer (IPizzaService).  Thats how I have ended up with Non Actions.  I don't like them this way.  See comment to @Hightechrider.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a new `IPizzaService` that handles pizza concerns and inject that?  The `IPizzaService` can take an `IToppingService` dependency too so it gets the topping service that has been injected into your controller class.

The service should, of course, work against domain model objects (not view model objects) as per comments below.  Use Automapper to map between them.

Comment: Not to get too far off topic but I want to use the MakePizza non action with a pizza model and then save or update it using my (already existing) IPizzaService.  Is it good practice to pass a pizzaModel to my IPizzaService?  This is where I think Darin smells something.

Comment: @nameEqualsPNamePrubeGoldberg, yes it is a smell to pass view models to service layer. I would recommend you using AutoMapper to map this view model into a domain model which you would then pass to the service for processing. And it's the service that will do all the processing so that you don't need NonActions.

Comment: I use automapper and I love it.  Your answer about passing a view model into the service layer is a god send.  I haven't done it because it didn't feel right.  My error I think was trying to process the model and then map everything over.  If you update your answer or just copy your message above I can check as this is the most complete.  Thanks Darin.

Answer (score 0):

Add the method to your `PizzaModel` class.

```
public class PizzaModel
{
    public static PizzaModel MakePizza(PizzaModel pm)
    {
        var toppings = _toppingService.GetAllToppings();
        //roll out dough
        //put toppings on pizza
        //bake pizza
        return pm;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about this `_toppingService`? Where it will come from inside this static method?

Comment: I thought about this as well and I didn't like the idea of passing my _toppingService to a static method.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a helperclass and call the method that you want to use in both controller.